# How to get random value from an array?

Tags: javascript

This is what I came up with but it doesn't work. I don't get an output.

Javascript.js

```
function randomnamegen() {
    var names = ["Mango", "Pul", "Bat", "Tim", "Mh", "Hei"];
    var namein = names(Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0));
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = namein;

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Cherry Cheese Danish</title>

</head>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="randomnamegen()">Click Me!</button>
    <p id="name"></p>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get an Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function JavaScript.js:3 in google chrome console.

Comment: Use square brackets to access array items: `names[...];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` square brackets for Arrays:

```
var namein = names[ Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0) ];
```

Also instead of using strictly `5` (while you have 6) you can let JS do the count:

```
Math.random() * names.length
```

```js
function randomnamegen() {
    var names = ["Mango", "Pul", "Bat", "Tim", "Mh", "Hei"];
    var namein = names[ Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length) ];
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = namein;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="randomnamegen()">Click Me!</button>
    <p id="name"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working pretty well. You have to change the () by [] in:

```
var namein = names(Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0));
```

The correct one is:

```
var namein = names[Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 0)];
```

The console was giving the following error: "Object is not a function".

Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/bvx2rgek/) to see a working example.

Hope it's useful!

Answer (score 0):

- Use square brackets
- There's no need to add 0

`var namein = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];`

or use `^ 0` for the rounding

`var namein = names[Math.random() * 5 ^ 0];`

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) implementation intended to shuffle arrays.

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue,
        randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

After shuffling the array you can retrieve values like this:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function retrieve() {
    return shuffle(array)[0];
}
```

In case you don't want your items to repeat:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    temp = [];

function retrieve() {
    if(temp.length > 0) {
        return temp.pop();
    } else {
        temp = shuffle(array.slice());
        return temp.pop();
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the optimal answer though.

```js
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue,
        randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}

var array = ["Mango", "Pul", "Bat", "Tim", "Mh", "Hei"];

function retrieve() {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = shuffle(array)[0];
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="retrieve()">Click Me!</button>
    <p id="name"></p>
```